# Concatenating space-separated numbers together in a batch file

Tags: dos, batch-file

I need to randomly generate a number of values in a batch file that share a certain range and concatenate them together separated by spaces. Everything works except for concatenating the space-separated numbers together. The specific problematic issue is concatenating with the numbers with spaces, how do I go about this?

The relevent portion follows:

```
::Assume %minA%, %maxA% and %randB% are defined correctly.
set /a randA=(%random% %% %maxA%) + %minA%
set agent_counter=0
:start_agent_loop
if %agent_counter% equ %randA% goto end
set /a randApos=(%random% %% %randB%) + 1
::supposedly (if I recall), simply having a space between %agent_starts%
::and %randApos% should do the trick, this doesn't seem to be the case.
set agent_starts = %agent_starts% %randApos%
set /a agent_counter +=1
goto start_agent_loop

:end
echo -A %agent_starts%
```

Ideally, this should print something like...

```
C:\Path\>genparams.bat
-A 2 4 5
```

Currently I get

```
-A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The following website (SS64.com)](http://ss64.com/nt/) is INVALUABLE for batch script reference.
There are excellent pages on [SET](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), [IF](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html), you name it.

The SET command is not very forgiving with extra whitespace. Also, set /a will apparently check all strings to see if they are a variable, so I don't think the %'s are required around maxA and minA. I assumed %random% was a special batch file variable that returns a random number, so I did not remove them from that. (though you might be able to)

Change:

```
set /a randA=(%random% %% %maxA%) + %minA%
```

To:

```
set /a randA=(%random%%%maxA)+minA
```

And change:

```
set agent_starts = %agent_starts% %randApos%
```

To:

```
set agent_starts=%agent_starts% %randApos%
```

Doing that (and setting a minA=1,maxA=10,randB=5), I got this on my first run: "-A 3 4 3".

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Indeed, all I needed to do was remove the spaces such that it looks like your fourth line of script and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Also, I modified the file with your first recommendation (removing superfluous % signs) and it continued to work, but now it looks cleaner. :) As you guessed, I did have to keep them for %random%.

Comment: Sweet - glad to help. I was dealing with a separate "spaces" type issue in a batch script today, so I felt your pain :)